# I am having issues with the 'Next/Head' meta tag

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, meta-tags

I have a NextJS project structure like the one below, but contrary to my expectations, the title "TEST" is not being passed to the meta tag.

Based on my assumption, the issue may be related to handling the isVisible in the ValidAuthProvider. If my assumption is correct, what could be the solution to resolve this?

_app.tsx

```
<ValidAuthProvider>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
<ValidAuthProvider>
```

useAuthWall.tsx

```
const useAuthWall = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  // some validations
  if (valid)
    setIsVisible(true);

  const ValidAuthProvider = useCallback(
    ({ children }) => {
      if (isVisible) {
        return children;
      } else {
        return <Loading />;
      }
    },
    [isVisible],
  );

  return {
    ValidAuthProvider: ValidAuthProvider,
  }
}
```

Page.tsx

```
const Page = () => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <meta property="og:title" content="TEST" />
      <meta name="twitter:title content="TEST" />
      <meta name="facebook:title" content="TEST" />
    </Head>
  );
}
```

I would like "TEST" to be passed as the title of the meta tag.